# How to display JSON single level menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a json file with all link images from specific folder like this

```
["http://img1.png","http://img2.png","http://img3.png","http://img4.png"]
```

And I want to create a `<ul>` list with this but I don't know how.
Can someone help me with a small example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using json you can connect http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetImagesList.aspx?contextId=c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9&Folder=_design/car-marques

```
$.post("http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetImagesList.aspx?contextId=c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9&Folder=_design/car-marques", function (json) {

    var html = '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        html += '<li><img src="'+json[i]+'" /></li>';
    }
    html += '</ul>';

    $('.contents').html(html);
});
```

Comment: This is working: http://jsfiddle.net/XBfMV/42/ .. and I have updated same code here also.. Please check it

Answer (score 1):

```
var urls = ["http://img1.png","http://img2.png","http://img3.png","http://img4.png"];

var ul = $('<ul>');

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var li = $('<li>');
    li.appendTo(ul);
    $('<img>').attr('src', urls[i]).appendTo(li);
}

var container = $('#container');
container.append(ul);
```

Comment: how to connect urls var with my json link..because my json is like this http ://etc.com/getimages.aspx?getfolder==design/cars and returns only this ["http://img1.png","http://img2.png","http://img3.png","http://img4.png"]

Comment: Load it via AJAX for example.

Comment: Hi @Adrian I have answered your question with ajax requrest

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've parsed it into an array `arr`, you can do:

```
var ul = $('<ul/>').append(arr.map(function(i) {
    return '<li><img src="'+i+'" /></li>';
}).join());
```

Where `arr` is `["http://img1.png","http://img2.png","http://img3.png","http://img4.png"]`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var arr_images = ["http://img1.png","http://img2.png","http://img3.png","http://img4.png"];

var html = '<ul>';
for(var i=0; i<arr_images.length; i++)
{
   var img_url = arr_images[i];
   html += '<li>';
   html += '<img src="'+img_url+'" />';
   html += '</li>';
}
html += '</ul>';

document.getElementById('your_div_id').innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function by jQuery API

```
var json = ["http://img1.png","http://img2.png","http://img3.png","http://img4.png"]
var div ='<ul>';
json.map(function (text){ 
    div += '<li><img src="'+ text + '" /></li>'
  });
div += '</ul>'

$("containerSelector").append(div)
```